# Passing data from ionic/angular modal using separate template html file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a simple Ionic mobile app although the answer likely lies with Angular. The app is really simple, displays a list of employees with an Add button which displays a modal, lets the user enter some details, click Save and it's persists the data to a back-end Firebase store. It has 1 controller and a simple service. Initially I had the template html for the modal inside script tags inside the index.html and it all worked fine. When I decided to structure things out and put the modal template in a separate html file, suddenly the data object assigned to ng-modal via the input boxes no longer passes any data to the event handler to save the data, instead it's always undefined. Everything else works as it should, the modal displays ok, the event handlers are calling the right functions etc. The only change is moving the input template to a separate file. I know it's likely something really simple but can't for the life of me work out why and can't find any info about it anywhere else.

Template HTML file for the modal :

```
  <ion-list>

    <h1>Add Employee</h1>

    <div class="list list-inset">

      <ion-item>
        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" ng-model="data.employeeName">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Age" ng-model="data.employeeAge">
        </label>
      </ion-item>

        <button class="button button-outline button-block button-balanced" 
          ng-click="addEmployee(true, data)">
            Save &amp; Add Another
        </button>

        <button class="button button-outline button-block button-positive" 
          ng-click="addEmployee(false, data)">
            Save
        </button>

        <button class="button button-outline button-block button-assertive" 
          ng-click="closeAddModal()">
            Cancel
        </button>

  </ion-list>

</ion-modal-view>
```

addEmployee event - data parameter is now always undefined. Worked fine with embedded template :

```
$scope.addEmployee = function(retainModal, data) {
    var employee = {employeeName:data.employeeName,
                     employeeAge:data.employeeAge};
    employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
    if (! retainModal) {
        $scope.closeAddModal();
    };
    data.employeeName = "";
    data.employeeAge = "";
};
```

Comment: Wheres the employeeService? Are youreturning a promise?

Comment: Not returning a promise. The addEmployee function doesn't get as far as calling the employeeService.saveEmployee as it errors out when trying to assemble the employee object as the data parameter is undefined when passed back from the template. This worked fine when the modal template html was within index.html but as soon as I moved it to it's own file I get this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this question and other needs I create a service that can be useful.

See this post: [Ionic modal service](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-modal-service-like-angular-ui-bootstrap-modal-review/15357) or see in operation: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/julianpaulozzi/pen/wBgpjM)

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'appModalService';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, [
    '$ionicModal', '$rootScope', '$q', '$injector', '$controller', appModalService
]);

function appModalService($ionicModal, $rootScope, $q, $injector, $controller) {

    return {
        show: show
    }

    function show(templateUrl, controller, parameters) {
        // Grab the injector and create a new scope
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
            ctrlInstance,
            modalScope = $rootScope.$new(),
            thisScopeId = modalScope.$id;

        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(templateUrl, {
            scope: modalScope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            modalScope.modal = modal;

            modalScope.openModal = function () {
                modalScope.modal.show();
            };
            modalScope.closeModal = function (result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
                modalScope.modal.hide();
        };
        modalScope.$on('modal.hidden', function (thisModal) {
            if (thisModal.currentScope) {
                var modalScopeId = thisModal.currentScope.$id;
                if (thisScopeId === modalScopeId) {
                    deferred.resolve(null);
                    _cleanup(thisModal.currentScope);
                }
            }
        });

        // Invoke the controller
        var locals = { '$scope': modalScope, 'parameters': parameters };
        var ctrlEval = _evalController(controller);
        ctrlInstance = $controller(controller, locals);
        if (ctrlEval.isControllerAs) {
            ctrlInstance.openModal = modalScope.openModal;
            ctrlInstance.closeModal = modalScope.closeModal;
        }

        modalScope.modal.show();

        }, function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }

    function _cleanup(scope) {
        scope.$destroy();
        if (scope.modal) {
            scope.modal.remove();
        }
    }

    function _evalController(ctrlName) {
        var result = {
            isControllerAs: false,
            controllerName: '',
            propName: ''
        };
        var fragments = (ctrlName || '').trim().split(/\s+/);
        result.isControllerAs = fragments.length === 3 && (fragments[1] || '').toLowerCase() === 'as';
        if (result.isControllerAs) {
            result.controllerName = fragments[0];
            result.propName = fragments[2];
        } else {
            result.controllerName = ctrlName;
        }

        return result;
    }

  } // end
})();
```

Usage:

```
appModalService
 .show('<templateUrl>', '<controllerName> or <controllerName as ..>', <parameters obj>)
 .then(function(result) {
     // result from modal controller: $scope.closeModal(result) or <as name here>.closeModal(result) [Only on template]
 }, function(err) {
     // error
 });
```

You can use another service to centralize the configuration of all modals:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('myModals', ['appModalService', function (appModalService){

var service = {
    showLogin: showLogin,
    showEditUser: showEditUser
};

function showLogin(userInfo){
    // return promise resolved by '$scope.closeModal(data)'
    // Use:
    // myModals.showLogin(userParameters) // get this inject 'parameters' on 'loginModalCtrl'
    //  .then(function (result) {
    //      // result from closeModal parameter
    //  });
    return appModalService.show('templates/modals/login.html', 'loginModalCtrl as vm', userInfo)
    // or not 'as controller'
    // return appModalService.show('templates/modals/login.html', 'loginModalCtrl', userInfo)
}

function showEditUser(address){
    // return appModalService....
}

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this , I have changed code a bit for my requirements, but really thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach your models to the scope:

```
$scope.data.employeeName = "";
$scope.data.employeeAge = "";
```

...and similar every time you reference them.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that but your suggestion made me just make absolutely sure. While it didn't work initially I then added a declaration of $scope.data={} at the top of the controller just to see and it did the trick. Cheers.

Comment: Yes you can't assign properties of an object (such as $scope.data) if the object itself does not already exist.